# JavaScript handling events after the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

When I'm writing some JavaScript I have a set of interface buttons that have their events assigned when the page is loaded. My problem is anything created dynamically wont receive these events.

For example, I'm making a URL checker, whose job is to make sure that any link that goes to another domain brings up an exit interface letting the user know they are leaving. Any links created after the page is loaded, post ajax (no pun intended) or whatever wont have that event naturally as those that existed when the page loaded.

In practice, what's the best way to ensure any newly created items get these sorts of global events?

I like to use jQuery, but this is really a conceptual question.

Should I create a function to re-apply any global link effects, or is there a smarter way besides doing it piecemeal?

Comment: As a curiosity, does anyone know how .live() works? Is it a timeout, or an actual dom event? Also could it handle more complex filters, for example when an href meets a set of requirements? (starts with http, etc)

Comment: @Bob: From [jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/#event-delegation): *The .live() method is able to affect elements that have not yet been added to the DOM through the use of event delegation: a handler bound to an ancestor element is responsible for events that are triggered on its descendants. The handler passed to .live() is never bound to an element; instead, .live() binds a special handler to the root of the DOM tree.* -- So it's like `delegate()` but works at the root of the DOM, and this is why it usually makes more sense to use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: @Bob: As far as using a selector to pick only attributes that start with "http", see jQuery's [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). In your case, you'd do something like `$('a[href^="http"').live(...)`

Comment: @Bob Google "jQuery live". First result.

Comment: @Sime I was actually reading the API page for it (http://api.jquery.com/live/ ), the reason I asked is because of the reference "DOM traversal methods are not supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector, as in the example above.", I wasn't sure if they were implying more advanced selectors were disabled.

Comment: @Šime: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: @treeface - That makes sense, I was trying to figure out if I could use a custom function to make selections, but that would work too.

Comment: @treeface I don't understand. What are you implying? I was commenting, not answering...

Comment: @Bob: That's a really good question, actually. I just tested it out and advanced selectors *do* indeed work. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KBEjL/

Comment: Very cool, sometimes I'm almost bothered trusting jQuery with so much, but it always seems to pull through.

Comment: @Bob: no need to feel bothered...read the source! Think of jQuery as a way to get around the fact that many browsers handle things differently and that there is usually a much more efficient way of doing the things you'd otherwise do in regular JS. In short, I trust jQuery much more than I trust myself.

Comment: Good point. As a side side side note, I spent about a half hour perusing jQuery's FAQ regarding post-document load events and how to handle them, and I didn't see one mention of ".live"anywhere... I'll have to see if I can find the page I was looking at and poke for change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using jQuery, you can use the **[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** method.

Normally when binding an event handler, the event handler is bound to a specific set of elements. Elements added in the future do not receive the event handler unless it is re-bound.

jQuery's .live() method works around this by binding its own special event handler to the root of the DOM tree (relying on event bubbling). When you click on an element, if it has no event handler directly attached, the event bubbles up the DOM tree. jQuery's special event handler catches the event, looks at its target and executes any user-specified event handlers that were assigned to the target through .live().

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.  It will allow you to attach to events when control are created during load, and whenever new ones are created.  There is a performance penalty, but it is not significant unless you are loading a lot of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.live()` jQuery method to add listeners to elements that are created after the page is finished loading. Using your example of the exit link (if I understand it correctly):

```
$(function(){
    $('a.exitLink').live('click',function(event){ /* do stuff when a link of class exitLink is clicked */);
});
```

This will respond to the `click` event on any link of class `exitLink`, regardless of when it was created (before or after `onload` fires).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes put simply, where you might have had this before:

```
$('selector').click(function () {});
```

Replace it with:

```
$('selector').live('click', function() {});
```